# useState array of arrays

Tags: reactjs

```
 const [newTag, setNewTag] = useState([]);

 const handleSubmitValue = (val, index) => {
    const newTagValue = [...newTag];
    newTagValue[index] = val[index];
    setNewTag(newTagValue);
  };
```

I want to push value of newTag have model like `[["aa","bbb], ["ccc","ddd"]]`

Comment: What happened when you did this?

Comment: I will be great if you could share the code of the component, and elaborate a bit more on what is it that you are trying to achieve with it, as more context you add to the question you will get better responses.